# Variable variables in OOP

Tags: php, oop, variables

I'm having a little struggle on this one and would appreciate some help.

In PHP variable variables can easily be defined like this

```
$a = "myVar";
$$a = "some Text";
print $myVar; //you get "some Text"
```

Now, how do I do that in a OOP enviroment? I tried this:

```
$a = "myVar";
$myObject->$a = "some Text"; //I must be doing something wrong here
print $myObject->myVar; //because this is not working as expected
```

I also tried `$myObject->{$a} = "some Text"` but it's not working either. So I must be very mistaken somewhere.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "variable variables can easily be defined" Please refrain from using them (in OOP or otherwise). You can thank me later.

Comment: I know what you mean and actually use them very rarely. Right now I'm having a situation where it makes sense.

Comment: If you are using variable variables, then you do not understand OOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class foo {
    var $myvar = 'stackover';
}

$a = 'myvar';
$myObject = new foo();
$myObject->$a .= 'flow';
echo $myObject->$a; // prints stackoverflow
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually doing right, the error was somewhere else where I forgot to access `$myObject->$a` but tried to get `$a` directly.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
class foo {
    var $myvar = 'stackover';
}

$a = 'myvar';
$myObject = new foo();
$myObject->$a = 'some text';
echo $myObject->myvar;
```